# Adding static button at the end of the row view for a dynamically generated list

Tags: android, listview

We are creating a list view by fetching the values from shared preferences. The work flow will be like this.

1. Customer login into the app and will click on Favorites Tab. For the First time a modal view will appear with toggle switches.
2. The Customer can select the toggle switches to add their favorite options and save it.
3. In  next login , when the customer clicks on the favorites tab, the list will be appearing with the options that he opted before.
4. Now we want to add a static button(for edit) at the botton, which on clicking will show up the modal view with the toggle switch page.

But when I am trying to add button in my XML file, i am getting button in each row. Your help in this regard will be greatly appreciable.

Layout(XML File)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="2dp"    

android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     >

</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="14dp" >
</TextView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

**dummy.java**

```
 import kvbank.kvb_epassbook.util.MobileArrayAdapter;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class dummy extends  ListActivity {
 //String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[15] ;
 ArrayList<String> MOBILE_OS = new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int count1 = sp.getInt("count", -1);
    String cc = String.valueOf(count1);
    System.out.println(cc);

    if((count1 == 0 ) || (count1==-1)){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, favorites.class);
        startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No favorites Set!!! =)",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    else
    {


          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

boolean ad = sp.getBoolean("accdet", false);
if(ad == true){
MOBILE_OS.add("AccountDetails") ;   
 }
boolean as =sp.getBoolean("accsumm", false);
if(as == true){
MOBILE_OS.add("AccountSummary") ;   
 }
boolean ast =sp.getBoolean("accstmt", false);
if(ast == true){
 MOBILE_OS.add("AccountStatement") ;    
 }
boolean crl =sp.getBoolean("CRL", false);
if(crl == true){
MOBILE_OS.add("Cash Remitance Limit") ; 
 }
boolean cse =sp.getBoolean("CSE", false);
if(cse == true){
MOBILE_OS.add("Cheque Status Enquiry") ;    
}
 boolean ic =sp.getBoolean("inwchq", false);
if(ic == true){
 MOBILE_OS.add("Inward Cheque") ;   
}
boolean uca =sp.getBoolean("Unclramt", false);
if(uca == true){
MOBILE_OS.add("uncleared Amount") ; 
}
boolean dt =sp.getBoolean("depdet", false);  
if(dt == true)
{
MOBILE_OS.add("Deposit Details") ;  
}    

setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));    

    }

}
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}   
}
```

**MobileArrayAdapter**

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import kvbank.kvb_ebook.R;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> mOBILE_OS) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_mobile, mOBILE_OS);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = mOBILE_OS;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values.get(position));

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values.get(position);


    if (s.equals("AccountDetails")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.acctinf);
    } else if (s.equals("AccountStatement")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.acctstat);
    } else if (s.equals("AccountSummary")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.acctsum);
    } else if(s.equals("Cash Remitance Limit")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cashret1);
    } else if(s.equals("Cheque Status Enquiry")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chqbkenq);
    } else if(s.equals("Inward Cheque")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.inwchq);
    } else if(s.equals("uncleared Amount")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.uncl1);
    } else if(s.equals("Deposit Details")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tddet);
    } else if(s.equals("Deposit Summary")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tdsum);
    } else if(s.equals("Deposit Statement")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dep_stmt);
    } else if(s.equals("Loan Details")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lndet);
    } else if(s.equals("Loan Summary")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lnsumm1);
    } else if(s.equals("Loan Statement")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.lnsumm1);
    } else if(s.equals("Alert Maintenance")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.alertreg);
    } else if (s.equals("Forex Rates")){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.forex1);
    }
    else if(s.equals("Cheque Book Request"))
    {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chqreq)   ;
    }



    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: you want to add the button at the end?? mean below the list ??

Comment: No not at the last of the list. The List will be scrollable, but the button should be static

Comment: Share your activity layout.

Comment: I already provided in the question

Comment: Its it your list item i think. I am asking about your activity layout which contains ListView. in your `dummy.java` where is `setContentView()` ??

Comment: That is the only layout for showing list view. You can see in MobileArrayAdapter

Comment: No other layout is available other than this. The other layout contains toggle switches and button to save the values to shared preferences

Comment: This is the link I used and i have done very minor changes to that http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: see my answer.. It may solve the problem..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a xml file **dummy.xml** paste the below code in that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_static"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="STATIC"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Change your **dummy.java** like below:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import kvbank.kvb_epassbook.util.MobileArrayAdapter;

public class dummy extends Activity {
//String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[15] ;
ArrayList<String> MOBILE_OS = new ArrayList<String>();
Button btn_static;
ListView mylist;
MobileArrayAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.dummy);

    mylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    //This is your Button use it any where you want..!!

    btn_static = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_static);

    final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    int count1 = sp.getInt("count", -1);
    String cc = String.valueOf(count1);
    System.out.println(cc);

    if ((count1 == 0) || (count1 == -1)) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, favorites.class);
        startActivity(i);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No favorites Set!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

        boolean ad = sp.getBoolean("accdet", false);
        if (ad == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("AccountDetails");
        }
        boolean as = sp.getBoolean("accsumm", false);
        if (as == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("AccountSummary");
        }
        boolean ast = sp.getBoolean("accstmt", false);
        if (ast == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("AccountStatement");
        }
        boolean crl = sp.getBoolean("CRL", false);
        if (crl == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("Cash Remitance Limit");
        }
        boolean cse = sp.getBoolean("CSE", false);
        if (cse == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("Cheque Status Enquiry");
        }
        boolean ic = sp.getBoolean("inwchq", false);
        if (ic == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("Inward Cheque");
        }
        boolean uca = sp.getBoolean("Unclramt", false);
        if (uca == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("uncleared Amount");
        }
        boolean dt = sp.getBoolean("depdet", false);
        if (dt == true) {
            MOBILE_OS.add("Deposit Details");
        }

        adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS);

        mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

        mylist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedValue = (String) adapter.getItem(position);
                Toast.makeText(dummy.this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;

            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks janki....for the code......can try it only tomorrow.......Will update the status

Comment: This works fine. But I have selected 9 toggle switches(restricted to 9) and clicked on save. Everytime  it is showing only 7 items and it is not scrolling further

Comment: Thanks I have solved the issue. Its my mistake while saving the shared preferences.. And thanks very much for your support and kindly help. Your answer helped me and marked it as an answer.

Comment: My pleasure it helped.. Happy coding :)